# Android Studio error when adding ImageView in fragment

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout, android-fragments

1- I have a fragment which has 2 EditText and 1 Button (below the code is)

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout                                                                                      xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
  xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  tools:context="com.example.junior_yao.fragmentfrombeginning.Top_Fragment"
  tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="81dp"
  tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="0dp">

  <EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:ems="10"
    android:hint="information"
    android:inputType="text|textShortMessage"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.503" />

  <EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:ems="10"
    android:hint="information"
    android:inputType="textPersonName"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="@+id/editText1"
    android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@+id/editText1"
    android:layout_marginTop="23dp"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/editText1"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0" />

  <Button
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Send Info"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="@+id/editText1"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@+id/editText1"
    android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/editText2"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.495" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

2- I have another fragment which has one Image View and 2 TextView

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout           xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
  xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  tools:context="com.example.junior_yao.fragmentfrombeginning.Down_Fragment"
>

  <ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/androidtest"
    tools:layout_constraintTop_creator="1"
    tools:layout_constraintLeft_creator="1"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
    android:id="@+id/imageView" />

  <TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Text2"
    android:textSize="25dp"
    android:textColor="#7FFF00"
    tools:layout_constraintRight_creator="1"
    tools:layout_constraintBottom_creator="1"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    tools:layout_constraintLeft_creator="1"
    android:layout_marginBottom="30dp"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent" />

  <TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Text1"
    android:textSize="25dp"
    android:textColor="#7FFF00"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    android:layout_marginTop="44dp" />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

On the 3rd part I add those 2 fragment in main activity layout
3 - if I add the first fragment only (I got no Error )

4 - Here the issue

If I add the 2nd fragment the app does not start , please help me to figure it out

```
      <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
     <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res       /android"
      xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
      xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="match_parent"
     tools:context="com.example.junior_yao.fragmentfrombeginning.MainActivity">

     <fragment
    android:id="@+id/fragment"
       android:name="com.example.junior_yao.fragmentfrombeginning.Top_Fragment"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="250dp"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    />

     <fragment
    android:id="@+id/fragment12"
      android:name="com.example.junior_yao.fragmentfrombeginning.Down_Fragment"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="250dp"
      android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
      android:layout_alignParentStart="true"

      />


     </RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here the java code for the 1st fragment

```
       package com.example.junior_yao.fragmentfrombeginning;


       import android.os.Bundle;
       import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
       import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
       import android.view.LayoutInflater;
       import android.view.View;
       import android.view.ViewGroup;


         public class Top_Fragment extends Fragment {



         public Top_Fragment() {
        }


         @Override
         public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup   container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

         return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_top, container, false);
}

         @Override
        public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
         super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
            }
         }
```

The java code for the 2nd fragment

```
         package com.example.junior_yao.fragmentfrombeginning;


          import android.os.Bundle;
           import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
         import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
         import android.view.LayoutInflater;
          import android.view.View;
           import android.view.ViewGroup;

          public class Down_Fragment extends Fragment {


           public Down_Fragment() {

                    }


               @Override
             public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                  // Inflate the layout for this fragment
                 return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_down, container, false);
}

               @Override
                     public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
           }
             }
```

Now the java code of the main Activity

```
        package com.example.junior_yao.fragmentfrombeginning;

        import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
         import android.os.Bundle;

         public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

           @Override
          protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
              super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
               setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
                  }
                 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add more information so you can be helped, the java code where the fragments are being called and created and the logcat as well to help solve the problem, the XML design code is not helpful.